# How to speed up image rotation?

Tags: android, image, rotation

I implemented button to rotate image in galleryview, but sometimes it perform it's work increadibly slow. I can take up tp 20 seconds. Is there a way to speed up it or to implement in better way then i did?

my code

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                onFront = (ImageView) view;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

}

    public void rotateS(View v) {
        ImageView iv = onFront;
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(geg);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
        geg = 90;
        Log.d("rorate", "yes");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved rotation logic to asyncTask